Why does call to Google STT not return transcript in spite of status 200?
Request to google speech to text api returns no result, but ok status 200 and totalBilledTime and requestId. I sent a request via postman but doesn't work either.
payload and code
{
  "audio": {
    "content": "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"
  },
  "config": {
    "encoding": "AMR_WB",
    "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
    "languageCode": "en-US"
  }
}

code:
 import { Audio } from "expo-av";
    import { MutableRefObject } from "react";
    import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
    import { Platform } from "react-native";
    import * as Device from "expo-device";
    import { readBlobAsBase64 } from "./readBlobAsBase64";
    
    export const transcribeSpeech = async (
      audioRecordingRef: MutableRefObject<Audio.Recording>
    ) => {
      try {
        await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
          allowsRecordingIOS: false,
          playsInSilentModeIOS: false,
        });
        const isPrepared = audioRecordingRef?.current?._canRecord;
        if (isPrepared) {
          await audioRecordingRef?.current?.stopAndUnloadAsync();
    
          const recordingUri = audioRecordingRef?.current?.getURI() || "";
          let base64Uri = "";
    
          if (Platform.OS === "web") {
            const blob = await fetch(recordingUri).then((res) => res.blob());
            const foundBase64 = (await readBlobAsBase64(blob)) as string;
            // Example: data:audio/wav;base64,asdjfioasjdfoaipsjdf
            const removedPrefixBase64 = foundBase64.split("base64,")[1];
            base64Uri = removedPrefixBase64;
          } else {
            base64Uri = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(recordingUri, {
              encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
            });
          }
          
          const dataUrl = base64Uri;

